# Install XULRunner 2.0

Tags: installation, xulrunner

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install xulrunner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43517/how-do-i-install-xulrunner)

I would like to try developing in XUL to see what the experiance is like.

How would I go about installing XULRunner 2.0 and the related SDK?

** EDIT 1**
This may be related
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xulrunner-2.0

I already tried adding 
deb http://ubuntu.mirror.cambrium.nl/ubuntu/ natty main universe

to /etc/apt/sources.list

As I could see XUL packages somewhere. However
`sudo apt-get install xulrunner-2.0` did nothing.