# How do I install XULRunner since it's a requeriment for Pencil?

Tags: software-installation, xulrunner

I'm installing Pencil and get the following error: `xulrunner: not found.` XULRunner is a a requirement for Pencil. So how do I install XULRunner and it's dependencies?

Comment: For installing pencil see http://askubuntu.com/questions/68488/how-do-i-install-pencil

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can install the latest source of XULRuner by executing:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-daily/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xulrunner-2.0 xulrunner-2.0-dev xulrunner-2.0-gnome-support xulrunner-dev
```

Once installed you'll need to update-alternatives so it's used by default:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config xulrunner
```

Be careful that this ppa also contains an updated version of firefox and thunderbird.

Comment: Ahh good I meant to install thunderbird when I got arround to it. and if FX breaks then I can fall back on chrome.

Answer (score 6):

You can actually run xulrunner apps without installing xulrunner, and just using firefox.

If you look on https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/XULRunner, it says:

> Firefox 3 and later ships with a private XULRunner package, which can run any compatible XULRunner application using the -app switch.

So I just untarred the pencil .tar.gz distribution, navigated into the user/share/pencil (or whatever) directory, and did:

```
firefox -app application.ini
```

tada!  No additional installations needed.

Comment: it works like magic!

Comment: I either forgot something, or it doesnt work anymore with Firefox 35.0.1. Any hints?

Answer (score 4):

You need to install one of the packages `xulrunner-1.9.2` or `xulrunner-2.0`, depending on which version of xulrunner you need.

Comment: On my Ubuntu 11.10, APT tells me, that the package is referenced, but not available?! Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Though late but anyone that stubles here, you don't need to download XULRunner anymore. just download their [deb from their site](http://evoluspencil.googlecode.com/files/evoluspencil_2.0.3_all.deb) and you are good to go.
Its working with Raring fine!

Answer (score 1):

There's no longer a recent package available.

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Getting_started_with_XULRunner

Put the following in a file and run it. It'll download a version that matches your current Firefox version, extract the files and create a symbolic link for convenience.

```
FIREFOX_VERSION=`grep -Po  "\d{2}\.\d+" /usr/lib/firefox/platform.ini`
ARCH=`uname -p`
XURL=https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/xulrunner/releases/$FIREFOX_VERSION/runtimes/xulrunner-$FIREFOX_VERSION.en-US.linux-$ARCH.tar.bz2
cd /opt
sudo sh -c "wget -O- $XURL | tar -xj"
sudo ln -s /opt/xulrunner/xulrunner /usr/bin/xulrunner
```