# How do I install Pencil?

Tags: 11.10, firefox, xulrunner

Pencil either runs as a Firefox extension or as a standalone application with XULRunner 1.9.2.

Trying to install XULRunner:

```
rich@rich-laptop:~/apps/pencil$ sudo apt-get install xulrunner-1.9.2 
[sudo] password for rich: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package xulrunner-1.9.2 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'xulrunner-1.9.2' has no installation candidate
```

So I tried to install it using Firefox by clicking on the install button on the [Pencil home page](http://pencil.evolus.vn/en-US/Home.aspx), and the .xpi file was downloaded and opened by an archive manager.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

### Addon Install

You can install the xpi file as a Firefox addon. To do this, drag the xpi file from your documents to Firefox. It should show a popup asking you about installing the package.

[image: drag and drop into firefox]
[image: installation screen]

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you haven't downloaded it yet, you can go to Tools -> Addons or about:addons in Firefox and search from as well as install from there.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try installing `xulrunner-1.9`. It seems to be a dummy package for the latest version of the 1.9 branch of xulrunner.

Answer (score 0):

Download the debian package file from https://code.google.com/archive/p/evoluspencil/downloads

Install using following command:

```
sudo dpkg -i <location_to_deb_file>
```

dpkg stands for debian package and i is for installation.