# How do I install xulrunner-1.9.2?

Tags: 11.10, xulrunner

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install xulrunner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43517/how-do-i-install-xulrunner)

I need it for Redcar. After "sudo apt-get install xulrunner-1.9.2." got an error:

"Package xulrunner-1.9.2 is not available, but is referred to by another package".