# Installing XULrunner, adding mozilla daily ppa doesn't help

Tags: installation, apt, ppa, xulrunner

I need to install xulrunner so I can use Redcar, but am unable to do so.  I followed the steps in this question verbatim [Install XULRunner 2.0](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41057/install-xulrunner-2-0).

Here's the output from adding the Mozilla PPA:

```
lpeabody@ubuntu:/var/www/drupal-7.8$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-daily/ppa
You are about to add the following PPA to your system:
 Official PPA for Firefox and Thunderbird daily builds
 daily (or even multiple builds per day) for various mozilla projects and branches.

For questions and bugs with software in this archive, please contact <email address hidden> or visit #ubuntu-mozillateam on freenode.
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mozilla-daily/+archive/ppa
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --secret-keyring /tmp/tmp.n2JGd679HN --trustdb-name /etc/apt/trustdb.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80/ --recv B34505EA326FEAEA07E3618DEF4186FE247510BE
gpg: requesting key 247510BE from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: key 247510BE: "Launchpad PPA for Ubuntu Mozilla Daily Build Team" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1
lpeabody@ubuntu:/var/www/drupal-7.8$ sudo apt-get update
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric InRelease
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com oneiric InRelease                                                                                
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates InRelease                                                                     
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports InRelease                                                                   
Get:1 http://extras.ubuntu.com oneiric Release.gpg [72 B]                                                                      
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric Release.gpg                                                                           
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com oneiric Release                                                                                   
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates Release.gpg                                                                   
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports Release.gpg                                                                                        
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com oneiric/main Sources                                                                                                    
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com oneiric/main i386 Packages                                                                                              
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com oneiric/main TranslationIndex                                                                                           
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric Release                                                                                                     
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates Release                                                                                                                    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports Release                                                                                                                  
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com oneiric/main Translation-en_US                                                                                                                 
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/main Sources                                                                                                
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/restricted Sources                                                                    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/universe Sources                                                                                            
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com oneiric/main Translation-en                                                                                             
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/multiverse Sources                                                                                          
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/main i386 Packages                                                                    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/restricted i386 Packages                                                              
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/universe i386 Packages                                                                
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/multiverse i386 Packages                                                              
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/main TranslationIndex                                                                 
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/multiverse TranslationIndex                                                           
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/restricted TranslationIndex                                                           
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/universe TranslationIndex                                                             
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/main Sources                                                                  
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/restricted Sources                                                            
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/universe Sources                                                              
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/multiverse Sources                                                            
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/main i386 Packages                                                            
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/restricted i386 Packages                                                      
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/universe i386 Packages                                                        
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/multiverse i386 Packages                                                      
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/main TranslationIndex                                                         
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/multiverse TranslationIndex                                                   
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/restricted TranslationIndex                                                   
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/universe TranslationIndex                                                     
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/main Sources                                                                
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/restricted Sources                                                          
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/universe Sources                                                            
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/multiverse Sources                                                          
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/main i386 Packages                                                          
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/restricted i386 Packages                                                    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/universe i386 Packages                                                      
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/multiverse i386 Packages                                                    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/main TranslationIndex                                                       
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/multiverse TranslationIndex                                                 
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/restricted TranslationIndex                                                 
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/universe TranslationIndex                                                   
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/main Translation-en                                                                   
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/multiverse Translation-en                                                             
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/restricted Translation-en                                                             
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/universe Translation-en                                                               
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/main Translation-en                                                           
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/multiverse Translation-en                                                     
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/restricted Translation-en                                                     
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/universe Translation-en                                                       
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/main Translation-en                                                         
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/multiverse Translation-en                                                   
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/restricted Translation-en                                                   
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/universe Translation-en                                                     
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security InRelease                                                                      
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric InRelease                                                           
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric InRelease
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security Release.gpg
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric Release.gpg
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security Release
Get:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric Release.gpg [316 B]
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric Release    
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/main Sources          
Get:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric Release [9,788 B]
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/restricted Sources
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/universe Sources
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/multiverse Sources
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/main i386 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/main TranslationIndex
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/multiverse TranslationIndex
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/restricted TranslationIndex
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/universe TranslationIndex
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main Sources
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main i386 Packages
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main TranslationIndex
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/main Translation-en
Get:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main Sources [1,650 B]
Get:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main i386 Packages [12.6 kB]
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/multiverse Translation-en       
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/restricted Translation-en       
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main TranslationIndex                      
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/universe Translation-en
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main Translation-en_US           
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main Translation-en
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main Translation-en
Fetched 24.5 kB in 5s (4,853 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
```

After running the update, I attempted to install xulrunner, but get the following back:

```
lpeabody@ubuntu:/var/www/drupal-7.8$ sudo apt-get install xulrunner-2.0 xulrunner-2.0-dev xulrunner-2.0-gnome-support xulrunner-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package xulrunner-2.0-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Package xulrunner-2.0 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'xulrunner-2.0' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'xulrunner-2.0-dev' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package xulrunner-2.0-gnome-support
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'xulrunner-2.0-gnome-support'
E: Unable to locate package xulrunner-dev
```

If you need to know anything else please specify, I will be prompt with my answers if asked during the next 2 hours... so 2am EDT.

Answer (score 2):

Iam sure Redcar expects that runtime somewhere. Why not download manually and manually place it in right location? it is dirty trick but it will definitely work!

**EDIT:**

As per Redcar installation on Ubuntu I cannot see any place they restrict to XULRunner version 2 or any version for that case. Have you checked with their instructions?

https://github.com/redcar/redcar/wiki/installation

**EDIT 2**

After few reading then it looks like Canonical removed XULRunner from repos and since the PPA does not work for you here is a link to download deb files. I have not tested them and I cannot guarantee safety. so try them at your own risk

http://mirror.pnl.gov/ubuntu//pool/universe/x/xulrunner-2.0/

Comment: I did try that, and I placed the path to xulrunner in my PATH variable, but no joy.

Comment: I added the line specified under Ubuntu installation instructions to /etc/apt/sources.list and am getting the same results...

Comment: Did you purge the ppa you added?

Comment: I'm not familiar with purging ppa's.  Do you know of a tutorial/procedure?

Comment: @LesterPeabody that's a separate question, try [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/98235/how-to-uninstall-the-experimental-hud-ppa) and then update your original question with the result, please.