# How to uninstall the experimental HUD PPA?

Tags: unity, 12.04, hud

I installed HUD via these two steps:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:unity-team/hud
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

I tested it, but now I have problems entering Applications Menus, e.g. by Pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> for `Edit Menu`.

So I want to uninstall and so I removed the ppa from the sources. I did this from the Settings Menu of the Update Manager. I think I need to remove the app by doing `sudo apt-get remove xxx.`

But I don't know how it is called... `hud-cli` isn't there.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:unity-team/hud
```

**If you've already manually removed the PPA from your sources**, re-add it so the purge can be conducted.

You may need to reboot before the uninstallation takes effect.

Comment: I get an error like this:
Warning:  Could not find package list for PPA: unity-team hud

Comment: I DID re-add the package... but they were unchecked inside the package manager. So now it's uninstalled. And after a reboot it's finally gone. Thank's a lot.