# How to resolve the "Failed to download repository" error?

Tags: updates, update-manager

I've tried to update but then I got this error

[image: failed to download repository information]

Here's the error information in that box:

```
W:GPG error: http://extras.ubuntu.com precise Release: 
The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 16126D3A3E5C1192 Ubuntu Extras Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>, 
W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/unity-team/hud/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found,
W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/unity-team/hud/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found, 
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

And my Internet connection is working fine.

After trying

```
$ sudo apt-get install ppa-purge 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
ppa-purge is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  language-pack-zh-hans language-pack-kde-en language-pack-kde-zh-hans
  language-pack-kde-en-base kde-l10n-engb kde-l10n-zhcn
  language-pack-zh-hans-base firefox-locale-zh-hans
  language-pack-kde-zh-hans-base
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

$ sudo ppa-purge ppa:unity-team/hud
Updating packages lists
W: GPG error: http://extras.ubuntu.com precise Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 16126D3A3E5C1192 Ubuntu Extras Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/unity-team/hud/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found    
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/unity-team/hud/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Warning:  apt-get update failed for some reason
PPA to be removed: unity-team hud
Warning:  Could not find package list for PPA: unity-team hud
```

I've tried

```
$ sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 16126D3A3E5C1192 
Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --secret-keyring /tmp/tmp.v6Ucus0B10 --trustdb-name /etc/apt/trustdb.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 16126D3A3E5C1192
gpg: requesting key 3E5C1192 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: key 3E5C1192: "Ubuntu Extras Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1
```

And then started the same procedure but of no use.

Answer (score 3):

I had same issue,
so here what I did to solve it:

- Open *Software Sources* from dash
- Switch to *other software* tab, uncheck the codes that are causing the issue, in my case it's http://ppa.launchpad.net/myunity...

then run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
```

and you should be able to run updater

Comment: Great suggestion, this solved it for me! My errors were `Some index files failed to download GPG error: http://apt.insynchq.com KEYEXPIRED <keynum>`

Answer (score 2):

You have the Unity team PPA on your computer, and you realllllllyyy don't want that on the release version of 12.04.

So, to fix that, follow the instructions outlined here:

[How to uninstall the experimental HUD PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/98235/how-to-uninstall-the-experimental-hud-ppa)

Then, to fix the GPG error, lets do this:

[What is the easiest way to resolve apt-get BADSIG GPG errors?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1877/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-resolve-apt-get-badsig-gpg-errors)

> sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 16126D3A3E5C1192

And then try again.

Answer (score -1):

I think I found a easier way that works for my Ubuntu 12.04 64bit in Toshiba c660 2e3.
I have followed the following command:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
```

This showed me that my PPA wasn't updating which was halting every other update as well and was showing a red triangular alert sign.

So I went to software updater, unchecked both PPA and kept only the Canonical one which then after refreshing started updating properly again. Also I chose the most acceptable mirror of my area.

Comment: Nope, did not work.

Answer (score -1):

Just open Update Manager and under the settings (bottom left) on tab authentication "restore default" after that everything went back to normal.