# Any success installing Rational Team Concert on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04

Supposedly Rational Team Concert is only supported for 10.04 Ubuntu. I suspect that with some tweaks, it could work on 12.04.

Please respond if you've been able to install RTC 4.0 on 12.04 Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I have RTC Client 4.0 working on Ubuntu 12.10.

Need to install: apt-get install ia32-libs

Then following the steps here:
[How do I install xulrunner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125980/how-do-i-install-xulrunner-in-12-04)

with modification ie using i686 not the output from uname.

Then edit the eclipse.ini file:
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath=/opt/xulrunner

It appears all works.

Hope that helps.